# How can i use Provider in flutter_native_splash package?

Tags: flutter

I want to get user's data from server and set State, when app is loading. so I use flutter_native_splash package and provider for app. the provider doesn't work.

stock_notifier.dart

```
class StockCodeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<StockModel> _stocks = [];
  String _stockCode = '';

  String get stockCode => _stockCode;

  void getStocks() {
    List<StockModel> data = allStocks;
    _stocks.clear();
    _stocks.addAll(data);
    _stockCode = _stocks[0].code;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

main.dart

```
void main() {
  WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);

  runApp(MyApp());
  
  Provider.of<StockCodeNotifier>(context).getStocks();

  FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<StockCodeNotifier>(
      create: (_)=>StockCodeNotifier(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, you may want to get the user data from the server without using Provider? and pass it via the MyApp constructor

Comment: `Provider.of<StockCodeNotifier>(context).getStocks()` will look for a `ChangeNotifierProvider` up in the widget tree with type of `StockCodeNotifier`. You can't use it in `main`, only below `MaterialApp`.

Comment: You can try to use a `FutureBuilder` to get async data and call `FlutterNativeSplash.remove()` after the future is completed.